# (Quasi)-Complete separation according to a random effect in logistic GLMM

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am experiencing convergence warning and very large group variance while fitting a binary logistic GLMM model using `lme4`. I am wondering whether this could be related to (quasi) complete separation according to the random effect, i.e., the fact that many individuals (the random effect/grouping variable) have only 0 in the dependent variable resulting in low within individual variation? If this could be a problem, are there alternative modelling strategies to deal with such cases?

More precisely, I am studying the chance that an individual is observed in a given status (having children while leaving by their parents) at a given age. In other words, I have several observations for each individual (typically 50) specifying whether the individual was observed in this state at a given age. Here is an example:

```
id  age status
 1   21      0
 1   22      0
 1   23      0
 1   24      1
 1   25      0
 1   26      1
 1   27      0
 ...
```

The chance to observe a status of 1 is quite low (between 1 and 5% depending on the cases) and I have a lot of observations (150'000 observations and 3'000 individuals).

The model was fitted using `glmer` specifying ID (individual) as a random effect and including some explanatory factors (age categories, parental education and the period where the status was observed). I get the following convergence warnings (except when using `nAGQ=0`) and very large group variance (here more than 25).

```
"Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 2.21808 (tol = 0.001, component 2)"
"Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue\n - Rescale variables?"
```

Here is the obtained model.

```
    AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
  9625.0   9724.3  -4802.5   9605.0   151215

Scaled residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max
-2.529 -0.003 -0.002 -0.001 47.081

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 28.94    5.38
Number of obs: 151225, groups:  id, 3067

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -10.603822   0.496392 -21.362  < 2e-16 ***
agecat[18,21)   -0.413018   0.075119  -5.498 3.84e-08 ***
agecat[21,24)   -1.460205   0.095315 -15.320  < 2e-16 ***
agecat[24,27)   -2.844713   0.137484 -20.691  < 2e-16 ***
agecat[27,30)   -3.837227   0.199644 -19.220  < 2e-16 ***
parent_educ     -0.007390   0.003609  -2.048   0.0406 *
period_cat80 s   0.126521   0.113044   1.119   0.2630
period_cat90 s  -0.105139   0.176732  -0.595   0.5519
period_cat00 s  -0.507052   0.263580  -1.924   0.0544 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) a[18,2 a[21,2 a[24,2 a[27,3 prnt_d pr_80' pr_90'
agct[18,21) -0.038
agct[21,24) -0.006  0.521
agct[24,27)  0.006  0.412  0.475
agct[27,30)  0.011  0.325  0.393  0.378
parent_educ -0.557  0.059  0.087  0.084  0.078
perd_ct80 s -0.075 -0.258 -0.372 -0.380 -0.352 -0.104
perd_ct90 s -0.048 -0.302 -0.463 -0.471 -0.448 -0.151  0.732
perd_ct00 s -0.019 -0.293 -0.459 -0.434 -0.404 -0.138  0.559  0.739
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of a few different optimizers available through the `nloptr` and `optimx` packages. There's even an `allFit` function available through the [afex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html) package that tries them for you (just see the `allFit` helpfile). e.g:

```
all_mod <- allFit(exist_model)
```

That will let you check how stable your estimates are. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97929/lmer-model-fails-to-converge) points over to more resources on the gradient topic.

If you're worried about complete separation, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132677/binomial-glmm-with-a-categorical-variable-with-full-successes/132678#132678) for Ben Bolker's answer to use the `bglmer` function from the [blme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blme/index.html) package. It operates much like `glmer`, but allows you to add priors to the model specification.